# Showing only the last 12 rows in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am a beginner to appscript. I am doing a resident payment system where the user will enter username and password first and after logging in they can view the payment history. For now it is showing the all the payment data in the database but I want to only show the last 12 rows. Can anyone help me on this me? I have attached some images and link to my appscript to explain myself better. Thanks in advance.

https://script.google.com/d/1xV7FDVgp10XbGFtPJDUnhqm1GYybKZeKEI2L84Slp34rndOWgVJ1iScm/edit?usp=sharing - Link to my appscript coding

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxFJTD9f6cMMDYDHw5sY6bENOmC52Z_7-mkGmnNGkQ-B5-j-63Q4aOcgetX4MWYIfW6/exec - Link to my executed version (Web App)

USERNAME : JJACKSON

PASSWORD : PASSWORD1

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySG30.jpg)

Comment: @Tanaike Bro if I am not mistaken, it will only minus 12 rows right. In the AppScript right every year new 12 rows ( which means in 2022 new rows will be added from January 2022 until December 2022). So this logic will be a problem later bro. Hope you will me in this bro. Thank you bro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I saw your script of your shared Google Apps Script project, in that case, how about the following modification? In this case, please modify the function of `displayTable()` at the HTML & Javascript side as follows.

#### From:

```
function displayTable(ar) {
```

#### To:

```
function displayTable(ar) {
  ar = ar.splice(-12); // <--- Added
```

- In your question, the users cannot directly see your script. So, I explain a little about this modification. In your script, the function is `displayTable` is called after `GetRecords` at Google Apps Script side was called, when "Login" button is clicked. In this case, the values from `GetRecords` is the 2 dimensional array. In this answer, the value you expect is retrieved from this array by `ar = ar.splice(-12)`.

#### Reference:

- [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

### Added:

From your following replying,

> Bro if I am not mistaken, it will only minus 12 rows right. In the AppScript right every year new 12 rows ( which means in 2022 new rows will be added from January 2022 until December 2022). So this logic will be a problem later bro. Hope you will me in this bro. Thank you bro.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
function displayTable(ar) {
```

#### To:

```
function displayTable(ar) {
  ar = ar.sort((a, b) => new Date(a).getTime() > new Date(b).getTime() ? -1 : 1).splice(-12); // <--- Added
```

- In this case, the last 12 months are retrieved from `ar`.
- If you want to retrieve the 12 months as the descending order, how about the following script?

  ```
    ar = ar.sort((a, b) => new Date(a).getTime() > new Date(b).getTime() ? 1 : -1).splice(0, 12);
  ```

Comment: Bro if I am not mistaken, it will only minus 12 rows right. In the AppScript right every year new 12 rows ( which means in 2022 new rows will be added from January 2022 until December 2022). So this logic will be a problem later bro. Hope you will me in this bro. Thank you bro.

Comment: @LEE WEI LIANG Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, I added one more modified script in my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize again.

Comment: Bro thank you so so much for your help . I really appreciate this help. Its working fine. Thank you bro.

Comment: But bro I do have another question would you help me with it. Sorry for disturbing you bro. In my link I do have a global variable called `var streetSheetName = "JALAN SANGGUL 4";` but it is updating the value bro. The value should be updated in `function checkLogin(username, password)` but its not working. Would you mind help me with it.  Thank you so much bro

Comment: @LEE WEI LIANG Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Owh sure . I have created a new post bro asking about that question bro. Thank you for the help bro.

Comment: @LEE WEI LIANG Thank you for your response. I would like to check it. And, when I could find the solution, I would like to answer it.